# How to read a string up until a comma, and then save that bit and display it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am able to read all the lines of a text file, separating each list item whenever a comma `{ " , " }` is reached. This is then displayed into a bootstrap collapse, however each item is displayed in their own collapse. So for example; say I were to have the following in my `.txt` file;

> John, 0

Both John and 0 would have their own collapsible. Instead, I want John to be the only one with a collapsible, and I want the 0 which is an ID, to be invisible to the user. I would assume one would perhaps use the 'substring' property to do this, but how?

Below is my following code that performs as the example above;

```
@{
    var result = "";
    Array userData = null;
    char[] delimiterChar = { ',' };

    var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Category.txt");
    userData = File.ReadAllLines(dataFile);

}

<div class="categoryList">

    @result
    @if (result == "")
    {
        foreach (String dataLine in userData)
        {
            foreach (string dataItem in dataLine.Split(delimiterChar))
            {

                <p>
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                        @dataItem
                    </a>
                </p>

            }

        }

    }
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) method returns a string array, so you just need to index it to pick the first element, in this way your inner foreach would be redundant as well, so something like this is most probably what you're looking for:

```
foreach (String dataLine in userData)
{
    <p>
        <a....>
            @dataLine.Split(delimiterChar)[0]
        </a>
    </p>
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, i see now. Sorry for the confusion. Thank you for making it very clear to me. Appreciate the help and time spent :)

Comment: @SeventhWarhawk You're Welcome. Glad to see it helped you.